# Chrome DevTools not loading HTTPS pages

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

On HTTP pages Chrome DevTools works as expected, but when I try to use DevTools to view HTTPS pages on **any** website, the page won't load and I see Chrome's generic "No internet" error message (ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED); the Network tab in DevTools shows my request but no response. Closing DevTools and reloading the HTTPS pages works perfectly (the page displays properly), just not when DevTools is open. This problem occurs on any HTTPS page on any website, it is not specific to a particular site/page. Restarting Chrome/computer does not help.

I'm using Chrome 108 latest on Win10, and DevTools with default settings.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same Problem.

For me it turned out that i had Network Throttling enabled.
I had turned it on for testing and forgot about it, now everytime i open my devtools my sites dont load/reload.
More Info: https://www.debugbear.com/blog/chrome-devtools-network-throttling

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of other readers who might come across this problem:

I accidentally discovered that after installing [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic) and configuring it to decode SSL/TLS traffic (inc. installing a certificate), I was able to not just use Fiddler to view the HTTPS page traffic, but now Chrome's built-in DevTools also started working as expected for these pages.